# How to start application from C# application?

Tags: c#, .net, process.start

how can i start any application from C#

i mean for example, if i have an openfiledialog and the user opened it and selected any file and opened it, i need this file to opened in its application whatever its extension and its default start application.

i have googled and found that Process.Start takes the file name and its application but i don't know what is the type of the file the user is going o open
thanks in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 5):

`Process.Start` has several overloads; you want [the one that takes only a `string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx). From MSDN:

> It can be of any file type for which the extension has been associated with an application installed on the system. For example the file name can have a .txt extension if you have associated text files with an editor, such as Notepad, or it can have a .doc if you have associated .doc files with a word processing tool, such as Microsoft Word.

Example:

```
Process.Start(myOpenFileDialog.FileName);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can call `Process.Start` with any filename and the file will open in its default program.

Comment: Yes, u can try  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("\test.exe","").

Ref : http://myewt.blogspot.com/2007/07/how-to-run-exe-from-running-program.html

Comment: @Ram: The point is that you can call `Process.Start(@"C:\Path\MyFile.doc") and it will open in Word.